# Ag Grid Material Sample - Select editor not working

Tags: material-ui, ag-grid

The mat select editor if not working in the ag grid material sample project:

https://www.ag-grid.com/example-angular-material-design/

When changing the vegetable in the editor the selected item is not getting propagated back to the grid.

I have downloaded the sample project and get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue logged for Angular Material component with Editors.

Refer: [ag-grid-pipeline](https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-pipeline/)

> **AG-2359**   *Investigating issues with popup editors not working anymore (ie Angular Material editors)*

Its status shown as <kbd>DONE</kbd>, so in the next release `19.1.5` or `20.0.0`, it should be fixed.